# Do we have any way to get OBIEE server analysis physical query?

Tags: oracle, obiee

> Do we have any way to get OBIEE server analysis physical query?

we can get OBIEE server analysis physical query from logs of Usage Tracking in which Session ID is embedded in the front.


I would like to compare Physical SQL statement(s) associated with the analysis/dashboard and i don't want to use logs of Usage Tracking. This task i am going to do pragmatically (Java).

I am using Oracle BI 12C server.

Comment: Use the v$_session view on the target server. The sessions will be coming from the NQ... userids. Then you'll be able to get the exact SQL in execution, live. Keep in mind (albeit this was for 11g), that the BIEE tends to submit multiple physical SQLs, while you expect only one when looking at the advance panel in the Analytics (logical SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Physical SQL is in Usage Tracking. If you insist on doing it programmatically through he application abstraction layer then you are talking about LSQL - logical SQL - because you work with the RPD and NOT the sources themselves!

Have a look here: https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2014/01/automated-regression-testing-for-obiee/

Edit: If you just want to generate the physical SQL without actually executing it against the source you can do that by calling another request variable in your LSQL:

set variable SKIP_PHYSICAL_QUERY_EXEC=1;

https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2015/03/obiee-nqcmd-tidbits

Comment: Ok let's consider through application abstraction layer/ web services we got Lsql (Logical Sql)  and using nqcmd we got corresponding result data set. Do we any option to convert logical sql to physical sql? I am interested in more of physical Sql of analysis not logical one.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, let me try this, I will get back soon with result :)